# How to delay liquid->geometry in fluid simulation?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

i want to simulate a waterdrop hitting a settled water surface using the fluid simulation in blender 2.82. For that i fill a bowl with water the first x frames and let it settle a while. Then after that, a mesh with a water drop shape should “emit” the water. For that i set it to

Type: flow
Flow type: liquid
Flow behaviour: geometry

I think this would work fine, but i don’t see any option to delay the water drop so that it just starts after a while and not at the beginning of the simulation (when the bowl still gets filled).
The inflow type has an option “use inflow” whlch can be keyframed, but the geometry type unfortunately does not.

Any options here?

Comment: I think there is an emission strength walue somewhere (whil in geometry) you could try to animate this. Unfortunately I can't look it up currently but it could be under the source tab (or something like that can quite remember)

Comment: There is an emission strength slider for the type but it just controls more or less particles coming from the geometry ... but there is still emission even if its turned to 0 ... so, unfortunately no success with this

Comment: Hm okay sorry then I am out